# Karma tests remotely on Selenium 3 hub

Tags: javascript, selenium, automated-tests, karma-runner

I run Karma JavaScript unit tests remotely on a Selenium hub with Chrome 66, Firefox 59, and Internet Explorer 11 on a Windows 7 VM. That worked well for Selenium 2. However, I recently had to update to Selenium 3.12 - and now only Chrome works, while on Firefox or Internet Explorer a browser window will open, but nothing else. The tests will not start on them. However, end-to-end tests with Protractor 5.3 work on both browsers. So, it seems that the Selenium 3 hub and its nodes are working correctly, while the actual problem is somehow connected to Karma and its launchers.

I cannot find any karma-(webdriver)-selenium-launcher which seems to support Selenium 3.

The relevant part of my Karma config looks like this (for IE, Firefox is similar):

```
customLaunchers: {
      'remote_ie': {
          base: 'WebDriver',
          browserName: 'internet explorer',
          config: {
            hostname: '...',
            port: '4444'
          },
          platform: 'ANY',
          version: 'ANY'
       }
```

As launchers (`base`), I've tried installing and using `karma-selenium-webdriver`, `karma-webdriver-launcher`, `karma-selenium-webdriver-launcher` - to no avail.

The Selenium node config for the Internet explorer VM:

```
    { 
     "capabilities": [
        {
         "browserName": "internet explorer",
         "version": "ANY",
         "platform": "ANY",
         "maxInstances": 4,
         "seleniumProtocol":"WebDriver",
         "ie.ensureCleanSession":true,
         "ie.forceCreateProcessApi":true,
         "ie.browserCommandLineSwitches": "-private"
        }],

    "nodeTimeout": 120,
    "port": 4411,
    "nodePolling": 2000,
    "registerCycle": 10000,
    "register": true,
    "cleanUpCycle": 2000,
    "timeout": 30000,
    "maxSession": 4
    }
```

Additional infos on versions used:

Karma: 2.0.2; geckodriver: 0.20; Internet Exlorer driver: 3.12.0 32-bit version

**Update**: updated Selenium to version 3.12 - didn't change anything.

Comment: Code trials please

Comment: @DebanjanB  This is not really a "coding" problem, but a config/components thing. I've added some bits of relevant config files.

Comment: Does this help https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-ie-launcher#running-ie-in-no-add-ons-mode?

Comment: @TarunLalwani I don't think this relates here. As far as I understand it, the ie-launcher is for running Internet Explorer directly on the same machine as karma runs. However, for me that's not the case. Karma runs on machine A, whereas IE is supposed to start on machine B where Selenium hub runs and starts IE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [karma-selenium-grid-launcher](https://www.npmjs.com/package/karma-selenium-grid-launcher). It uses [selenium-webdriver](https://www.npmjs.com/package/selenium-webdriver) instead of [wd.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/wd) (only selenium 2)